# Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Services - IE11 Scrolling getting stuck

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, internet-explorer-11

Recently, a number of our remote desktop users on 2012 R2, have been finding IE 11 occassionaly gets into a state whereby they can't scroll up or down on a page they have been working on.

Mouse wheel doesn't work, arrow keys don't work, and while you can click on the vertical scrollbar and it darkens (to indicate it has been clicked on), when dragging it up and down it doesn't move.

Refreshing the page, or sometimes duplicating the tab, seems to resolve the issue.

Is anyone aware of any recent updates that may have introduced this issue? We aren't clear on when the issue started, so we don't know how far back to check on our updates that have been installed.

Comment: Can I ask if it happen on the same website for all users, or any website ?

Comment: Seems to affect various websites, and various users.

Comment: Does it happen running IE with no add-ons?

Comment: I can't really say. The only way to test is to get our entire user base running IE11 in this mode for a few days, but that would cause way to may headaches and complaints from users for us to test.